# Multiple Google Analytics in iPhone App

Tags: ios4, google-analytics

in my apps I am using GA in order to know app usage and os version installed.
my client would like to track some events, is it possible to use multiple account in the same app?

Thanks a lot

Thierry

Comment: Why would you need an extra account to track the extra events?

Comment: One for me (for tracking ios versions), and one for my client (for tracking events non interesting for me). I don't have access to my client's account.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically yes, you'd just need two separate tags and two different account codes.